# Streamsets Pipeline to ingest files to HDFS throwing misleading "File not Found" Exception

Tags: streamsets

We have a Streamsets job set up. Which although it runs successfully throws the following error:

> "UNKNOWN com.streamsets.pipeline.api.StageException: SPOOLDIR_35 -
>   Spool Directory Runner Failed. Reason
>   java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: "

The error is ‘file not found’ but actually the file is processed successfully and still the error is raised. This happens intermediately and not for all the files that are being processed.

Here's some background about the job:

- The pipeline reads files from the linux edge node and ingests them
  into HDFS
- The error occurs on the ‘read’ stage
- We have been running the same pipeline for almost 2 years and have
  not seen this issue until the last month or so. Nothing about our
  process has changed recently. The intermittent errors seem to
  coincide with the latest StreamSets upgrade.
- We process about 7
  files every 2 hours through this pipeline, so roughly 84 files a day,
  and the intermittent error seems to occur on 1-3 files per day. All
  files are still processed in to HDFS.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can I ask why this is tagged with `apache-spark`?  Also, are you using more than one thread in the directory origin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be hitting [SDC-9740](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-9740). Please watch/vote/comment on this issue, especially if you can provide any more detail that might help us narrow down the cause. It's a P1, so it should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: We increased the spooling period and the occurrences of this error decreased. Iam guessing it has something to do with the Spooling Period.